# Python - read in a previously 'list' variable from file

Tags: python, string, file, list

I previously created a `list` and saved it to a file 'mylist.txt'. However, when I read it in it's a string, meaning I can't access each element as I like. I have been trying and searching for ways to fix this, but to no avail.

In the text document, the list is one line and looks something like:

```
[(['000', '001', '002'], ('010', '011', '012')), (['100', '101', '102'], ('110', '111', '112'))]
```

so that if this list was equal to `mylist`, I could do

```
>>> print mylist[0]
(['000', '001', '002'], ('010', '011', '012'))
>>> print mylist[0][0]
['000', '001', '002']
>>> print mylist[0][0][2]
002
```

etc.

The above is useful to me, but reading in the list has the following effect:

```
>>>myreadlist=open("mylist.txt",'r').read()
>>>myreadlist
"[(['000', '001', '002'], ('010', '011', '012')), (['100', '101', '102'], ('110', '111', '112'))]"
>>>myreadlist[0]
'['
>>>print myreadlist[0]
[
>>>myreadlist[:15]
"[(['000', '001'"
```

etc.
I know the format of `mylist` is bad, but it works for what I want and it took a very long time to generate it. I've tried just copy-pasting the list to python like `mylist = <paste>`, but the list is far too long and I get a memory error.

Is there a way to read the file and use it as a `list` so I can access each element like normal (i.e. as shown in the first print statements above)?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass the string to [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). It will safely parse the string into the appropriate structures:

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
        data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
>>> # You're done!
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much, this has been giving me such a headache. Consider this "Solved"!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a plain text file in your app? Assuming you have it correctly formatted as a Python list you can turn it into Python code instead of text. Rename the file `mylist.py` and at the front of your list add an assignment like `mylist = [xxx]`.

Within the Python script that requires access to this list you can import it like `from .mylist import mylist` which will allow you to do your work (e.g. `mylist[0]` etc.).

The above import assumes that the `mylist.py` and your Python script are in the same module (the same directory with a `__init__.py` file inside it). If that's not clear to you (have a look at [Python modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)) simply copy the entire list into the same file as your script and make the assignment at the top of the same file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and info. It doesn't have to be a .txt file, however I find @icktoofay 's response most useful and will be using that method in this particular instance.